# Custom Search Icon in Action Bar Search

Tags: android

I need my custom search icon instead of default search icon on action bar. Below is my xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/filter"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@null"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/list_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

For filter its showing the image I have used in `android:icon` but for search its displaying the default one. I am not sure if I am missing something. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this help you   

 <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
       android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
       android:icon="@drawable/list_search"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
```